# Why do we slap ones in the lstsq function of numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I am trying to understand the use of [lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html?highlight=lstsq#numpy.linalg.lstsq) function with numpy in finding the slope and intercept given the values of `x` and `y`. Going through an example in the documentation linked above with the given `x` and `y` values,

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1])
```

I do not understand the step where:

```
A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T  # THIS STEP 

m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
```

What has been done here? Could someone please explain to me the step where the documentation example uses `np.ones` function? What does `np.ones` do here?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is it "what does `np.ones` do"? Is it "what will `A` look like after doing this `np.vstack`"? Is it "why does `A` need to have this value for the code to work as intended"? Or something else?

Comment: Also: did you try reading the text on that page in between the code statements? If it's unclear, I think you might actually have a math question rather than a programming question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The question is `what does np.ones do`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yeah, it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The "ones" reflect the intercept. The general form of the least square solution is `y=X beta` where `beta` are the coefficients: intercept and slope.

As individual equations it's

```
y_1 = beta_0 + beta_1 * x_1
y_2 = beta_0 + beta_1 * x_2
y_3 = beta_0 + beta_1 * x_3
.
.
.
```

and if you write it in a matrix form the *design* matrix `X` (same as in `y=X beta`) includes a column of ones.

for more info have a loot at the simple regression example on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: it explains why the matrix A has 2 columns: one column containing the data points x_i and a second column on ones.